# Convert 1 pandas dataframe row into string

Tags: pandas

I have this code to extract one row into string,
but would like to make it in more time efficient way:

```
d= dfb_all[ dfb_all.uuid == x["uuid"] ].iloc[0,:].tolist()
d= d.join('_')
```

is there any alternatives ?

EDIT :
  The base problem is to map some rows from dataframe dfb_all
  into dataframe  df1  using uuid as column key

is there any efficient to do key mapping between 2 dataframes in pandas ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
i = (dfb_all.uuid.values == x['uuid']).argmax()
d = '_'.join(dfb_all.values[i].astype(str).values.tolist())
```

---

I think.  Hard to tell when you didn't provide sample data.

Comment: dataframe are just string or int values

Answer (score 0):

From PiRSquared answer, this is corrected and turn to be faster:

```
i = (dfb_all.uuid.values == x['uuid']).argmax()
'_'.join(dfb_all.iloc[i, :].values.astype(str).tolist())
```